# SoapUI/Groovy: expand txt file, NOT re-write it

Tags: groovy, soapui

There is no problem to save response sheet to file. Smth like

```
def xmlFile = "C:/.../Try.xml"
def response = context.expand( '${Request#Response}' )
def f = new File(xmlFile)
f.write(response, "UTF-8")
```

BUT.

I re-run my request in groovy script with new parameters (using while), and I need to ADD info to result file, not to re-write it. Now it's just re-writing each time:(. File created outside the cycle.

Thanks in advance,
Dmitry

Comment: Open it in append mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

straight from the [ref-doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN2025-Streams)

```
new File('TestFile1.txt').withWriterAppend( 'UTF-8' ){ w->
  w << 'abcdefghij'
}
```

Comment: just note: instead of 'abcd' - insert var or whatever we want